# Scheme function to determine whether the list follows a pattern

Tags: scheme

Scheme: A function which will determine if a passed in list follows an A B pattern.  An AB pattern would be (A B A B A B) or (A B) or any combination of A and B repeated.  A and B are not variables, I literally mean a letter A followed by a letter B.

Comment: What should it evaluate to when input is `'(A B A)`?

Answer (score 0):

A naive, but simple, algorithm: look for the pattern at the head of the list; if it matches return true, if it doesn't look for the pattern in the rest of the list.

```
(define (sublist? pattern list)
  (and (not (null? list))
       (or (match? pattern list)
           (sublist? pattern (cdr list)))))
```

and the `match?` function can be:

```
(define (match? p l)
  (or (null? p)
      (and (not (null? l))
           (eq?    (car p) (car l))
           (match? (cdr p) (cdr l)))))
```

Comment: Please provided an 'answered' check and up-vote (when you can).